# Find all cells, in a column of characters or strings, that match "a"

Tags: google-sheets, sum, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

How do I look through a column of characters or strings, and find all cells in said column that matches with "a" and then add a value from a cell in the same row to (E2) the sum?

I have illustrated it in this picture:

[image: I have illustrated it in this picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D2 put:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A,"=a",B2:B)
```